# Estilizar "bolinhas" de quadrado editável

Tags: javascript, google-maps, maps, google-maps-api-3

Quando desenho um quadrado editável no mapa, aparece aquelas "bolinhas" nos cantos, que são as áreas clicáveis para redimensionar o quadrado.

```js
function initMap() {

      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 10,
        center: {lat: 44.5452, lng: -78.5389},
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
      });

    // [START region_rectangle]
      var bounds = {
        north: 44.599,
        south: 44.490,
        east: -78.443,
        west: -78.649
      };

      // Define a rectangle and set its editable property to true.
      var rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle({
        bounds: bounds,
        editable: true
      });
    // [END region_rectangle]
      rectangle.setMap(map);
}
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>

<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap"></script>
```

Tem como estilizar aquelas "bolinhas"?

Comment: Poderia editar a pergunta com um print quanto a "bolinha" que está falando? Acabei confundindo com os marcadores.

Comment: Tem como colocar um print?

Comment: Editei o post, coloquei o link

Answer (score 1):

Cara. Eu sei que você pode estilizar a área do retângulo em si:

```
var bounds = {
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35,
    north: 44.599,
    south: 44.490,
    east: -78.443,
    west: -78.649
};
```

Eu dei uma olhada na net e achei esse link que mostra os corners de uma forma diferente: http://googlemaps.googlermania.com/google_maps_api_v3/en/poly_containsLocation.html

Talvez isso te ajude. =)

Comment: Os screenshots da página indicada foram feitos com uma versão mais velha da API, por isso estão quadradinhos.